# Excel Interop Problems - C#

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, interop

I have a problem with Excel Interop objects. I can't seem to pinpoint the problem either. (My code is at the bottom). Basically, sometimes it reads the cells correctly, but sometimes it doesn't. After two passes, it stops reading entirely. I think I have a math issue, but I can't find it. I would get someone else to read my code, but I don't have anyone nearby. I'll be on for awhile to answer questions. Thanks for the help, its a bit frustrating on why it doesn't work.

```
if(requiredEnd == true && requiredPass == true && requiredPath == true && requiredStart == true && requiredUser == true && requiredSheet == true)
        {
            errorCheck = false;

            try
            {


                //starting Excel
                Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
                excelApp.Visible = false;
                Excel.Workbook workBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath);
                Excel.Sheets sheet = workBook.Worksheets;
                Excel.Worksheet workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)sheet.get_Item(sheetName);


                //Generating User and Password
                int startCoordI = Int32.Parse(startCoord);
                int endCoordI = Int32.Parse(endCoord);
                int value = startCoordI;
                string combinedUser = userCoord + startCoord;
                string combinedPassword = passwordCoord + startCoord;
                string Username = Convert.ToString(workSheet.Cells.Named(combinedUser).Value);
                MessageBox.Show(Username);
                string Password = Convert.ToString(workSheet.Cells.Named(combinedPassword).Value);
                MessageBox.Show(Password);

                try
               {

                    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo proccessStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("net", "user " + Username + " " + Password + " /add /passwordchg:no");
                    System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process { StartInfo = proccessStartInfo };
                    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    proccessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    for (I = startCoordI; I <= endCoordI; I++)
                    {
                        proc.Start();

                        //new user
                        value++;
                        combinedUser = userCoord + value;
                        combinedPassword = passwordCoord + value;
                        Username = Convert.ToString(workSheet.Cells.Named(combinedUser).Value);
                        MessageBox.Show(Username);
                        Password = Convert.ToString(workSheet.Cells.Named(combinedPassword).Value);
                        MessageBox.Show(Password);
                    }

                    //Clean up Excel
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApp);
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workBook);
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sheet);
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workSheet);


                    //Executing.Show
                    proc.WaitForExit();
                    //Executing.Close


                     if(proc.HasExited == true)
                     {
                         if(errorCheck == false)
                         {
                             MessageBox.Show("The Process Has Been Completed!");
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             MessageBox.Show("Operation Ended With Errors. Exiting Excel Reader.");
                         }

                         proc.Close();
                         this.Close();
                     }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
           catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            if(requiredEnd == false || requiredPass == false || requiredStart == false || requiredUser == false || requiredSheet == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You Have Missing Required Fields!");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("That Is Not A Valid File!");
            }
```

There is a lot of "un-needed" parts there, but I thought giving the whole thing would be more helpful. (Most of the textboxes are just debug things, BTW)

EDIT: I forgot .Named wasn't part of the normal code. Its a function someone made for me:

```
    public static class ExcelExtensions
{
    public static Range Named(this Range Cells, string CellName)
    {

        char cellLetter = CellName.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper()[0];
        int xCoordinate = (cellLetter - 'A') + 1;
        int yCoordinate = int.Parse(CellName.Substring(1));
        return Cells[xCoordinate, yCoordinate];
    }
}
```

It basically allows you to use PowerShell themed coordinates, i.e (A1, B3 etc.)

Comment: what it reads when it's wrong?

Comment: @Gusman Hello again Gusman! I appreciate your help last time. Here is a Imgur gallery of what happens: http://imgur.com/a/QfVN3

Comment: well it's because Excel has the X and Y coordinates swapped, my fault sorry, change return Cells[xCoordinate, yCoordinate]; to return Cells[yCoordinate, xCoordinate]; and it will work

Comment: @Gusman Sorry to bother you again, I really appreciate your help. The only problem I have left is that It only creates the first user. I apologise for my noobie-ness, I am brand new to C#, and Excel Interop. I am just going off my general coding knowledge. I think the problem is that I initiliaze the net.exe from outside the For loop, but if I don't create it outside the loop I can't reference it later in the code.

Comment: you gave yourself the response, you are executing just once the process to create the user and it must be done in the loop. instead of waiting at the end (that's why you need the process outside the loop) wait it to finish inside the lop, in this way when the loop ends all the users will be created

Answer (score 0):

Gusman has answered my question in the comments, so I will explain here. My problem was that I had the x and y coordinates swapped, and that I didn't have the process inside the loop. Thank you Gusman!